# How to export the legend (Layers Panel) as an image in QGIS using the Python console?

Tags: qgis, python

I want to export the Legend (the Layers Panel) as an image using the python console.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Question body to make what you are asking much clearer, please?  Be aware that your Question title and tags are intended to summarize what is in the body so focus on getting all relevant information into the body first (and do the title and tags after that).